# xamarin android nullreference exeption on realdevice

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm devolping app with xamarin my app works perfectly fine on vs emulator
with the version of the android installed on vs emulator is 4.4 Kitkat
but when I want to test on the real device witch is version 4.1 JellyBeans

I get this errors:

> Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External] 01-09 12:51:08.901
>   W/dalvikvm( 8901): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16442:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
>   (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V 01-09 12:51:08.901 W/dalvikvm(
>   8901): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;) 01-09 12:51:08.901 W/dalvikvm( 8901):
>   VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16444:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested
>   (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z 01-09 12:51:08.901 W/dalvikvm( 8901):
>   VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16448:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode; 01-09
>   12:51:08.901 W/dalvikvm( 8901): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   505: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
>   01-09 12:51:08.911 W/dalvikvm( 8901): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 527: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I 01-09
>   12:51:08.991 W/dalvikvm( 8901): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   16341: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V 01-09
>   12:51:09.001 W/dalvikvm( 8901): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   317: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList
>   (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList; 01-09 12:51:09.011 W/dalvikvm(
>   8901): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 468:
>   Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable
>   (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   01-09 12:51:09.011 W/dalvikvm( 8901): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 470: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity
>   (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   01-09 12:51:09.031 E/dalvikvm( 8901): Could not find class
>   'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   01-09 12:51:09.031 W/dalvikvm( 8901): VFY: unable to resolve
>   instanceof 197 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in
>   Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper; An unhandled
>   exception occured.
>
> 01-09 12:53:38.511 I/MonoDroid( 8901): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 01-09
>   12:53:38.591 I/MonoDroid( 8901): System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. 01-09 12:53:38.591
>   I/MonoDroid( 8901):   at SPlus.MainActivity.ButtonAnimation ()
>   [0x00045] in <104b5b2031514a85ad3584f45248f342>:0  01-09 12:53:38.591
>   I/MonoDroid( 8901):   at SPlus.MainActivity.OnCreate
>   (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0001c] in
>   <104b5b2031514a85ad3584f45248f342>:0  01-09 12:53:38.591 I/MonoDroid(
>   8901):   at
>   Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_
>   (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in
>   <6296d3d76c5d4378959a1d9bf7205023>:0  01-09 12:53:38.601 I/MonoDroid(
>   8901):   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:9285ad27-0d09-44cd-b0d0-db82974f3544
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) 01-09 12:53:38.621 W/dalvikvm( 8901): VFY:
>   unable to resolve direct method 18401: Ljava/lang/Throwable;.
>   (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;ZZ)V An unhandled exception
>   occured.
>
> 01-09 12:53:40.881 E/mono    ( 8901):  01-09 12:53:40.881 E/mono    (
>   8901): Unhandled Exception: 01-09 12:53:40.881 E/mono    ( 8901):
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. 01-09 12:53:40.881 E/mono-rt ( 8901): [ERROR] FATAL
>   UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

I did set the compile to android 7.0 and minimum is 4.1 and target to compiled version.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

i did found the answer for this problem.

- first of all delete the shared library and the app from the device
- delete the support library's installed on device
- clean solution
- rebuild
  Done.